TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')
I want to use idl for the backend, but when initializing it there are some errors, I really tried many ways but can't fix it, thank you everyone for your help.
code
import { Sleep } from "./Sleep";
import idl from "./idl.json";

import { clusterApiUrl, PublicKey, Connection } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { IdlAccounts, Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";

const programId = new PublicKey("8AW5tuZCCxG5zm6Tu3C4APokQKFBuYN7qFHrxqVXnRye");
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

export const program = new Program<Sleep>(idl as Sleep, programId, {
  connection,
});



error
⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')


Is the idl variable of some value? Is the ./idl.json loaded properly from the place?

i don't know, but i copy from target/types/file.ts  and I use it in my backend

Then maybe a different thing. Before some time I had an issue when having the idl.json and idl.ts within the same directory. Could be the ./Sleep is the generated IDL as a typescript file? Then I would recommend getting the program instance like
import { Sleep, IDL } from "./Sleep";
Program<Sleep>(IDL, programId, provider)


thank you so much

I'm glad if it helps. I will summarize my thoughts here in the response for not being necessary to search it in the comments.

The problem could be related to incorrect IDL loading. Then it's good to verify the contents of your ./id.json file. While based on the discussion, it seems this isn't the issue.
Then, I encountered a problem in creating the Anchor program instance when idl.json and idl.ts were in the same directory.
Assuming ./Sleep is the generated TypeScript IDL:

Remove ./id.json from the directory where the idl typescript Sleep.ts resides
Modify the way how the Anchor program instance is loaded

import { Sleep, IDL } from "./Sleep";
Program<Sleep>(IDL, programId, provider)


thank you so much

Feel free to mark the answer as a correct one :-)
